# Using other functions' replacement rules

Tags: options, optional-arguments, default

I have a module that uses some default options for `NDSolve` like so

```
Options[f] = {WorkingPrecision -> 20};
f[p_, opts:OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{}, NDSolve[{eqns[p], bcs, FilterRules[{opts},Options[NDSolve]]]]
```

But this doesn't pass the changed default to `NDSolve` unless they are passed explicitly by the call to `f`. I seem to be missing something, because I am trying to avoid duplication: I would like to be able to simply add/remove options from the defaults of `f` and not have to change the body of `f`, and have these defaults passed to `NDSolve`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the fact that rules apply in the order in which they appear:

```
Options[f] = Join[{WorkingPrecision -> 10}, Options[NDSolve]];
f[opts : OptionsPattern[]] := NDSolve[..., FilterRules[Join[{opts}, 
    Options[NDSolve]], Options[NDSolve]]]
```

The same principle can also be used to specify default parameters so that `OptionValue` will automatically fall back on the defaults of `NDSolve` unless otherwise specified. Consider this example:

```
Options[f] = {a -> 1, a -> 2, b -> 3};
f[opts : OptionsPattern[]] := OptionValue[a]
f[]
```

> `1`

It shows that default values are considered in the order in which they appear, i.e. the default value for `a` in this function is 1 and not 2.

Similarly, you can also write

```
Options[f] = Join[{WorkingPrecision -> 10}, Options[NDSolve]];
f[opts : OptionsPattern[]] := OptionValue[WorkingPrecision]
f[]
```

> `10`

and be assured that whatever you specify overrides whatever `NDSolve` used.

And if we combine the two approaches we get to this:

```
Options[f] = Join[{WorkingPrecision -> 10}, Options[NDSolve]];
f[opts : OptionsPattern[]] := NDSolve[..., FilterRules[Join[{opts}, 
    Options[f]], Options[NDSolve]]]
```

which will take into account default options of `NDSolve` that you have overridden.

These patterns are probably used quite extensively in the built-in functions. The plotting functions also take the options from `Graphics` for example, I imagine this is how that is done.

Comment: Yeah, I was never sure about the order, and always too lazy to check and unsure that it would remain invariant in different versions etc. Do you mean `FilterRules[Join[{opts}, Options[f]], Options[NDSolve]]]`?

Comment: @bjorne Yes, that is what you would use if you had overridden some of the options when specifying defaults for `f`.